# Truncating File in Bash

Tags: bash

I am writing the output of a command into a bash file. The command gradually produces output, and I am using grep to retrieve part specific lines, and tee to write it to the file. Right now, the command is writing all the lines into the file. I want the file to be truncated everytime the bash command has some output, such that there is always one line in the file. How can I achieve such an effect?

The command I am using is:
`2>&1 zypper -x -n in geany | grep -o --line-buffered "percent=\"[0-9]*\"" | tee /var/log/oneclick.log`

This produces output like `percent="10"` and so on. Each time, only one line should exist in the file

Comment: The `ps aux` answer given seems to indicate that the operation desired is concatenation rather than truncation. Truncating means cutting short. Concatenation means adding together. If you want to accumulate multiple results, the operation is concatenation, not truncation.

Comment: i need to truncate and not concatenate. the `aux` command is concatenating instead of truncating

Comment: Then please expand your question with an example of what you want to happen.  It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to overwrite the file for each line:

```
2>&1 zypper -x -n in geany | 
grep -o --line-buffered "percent=\"[0-9]*\"" |
while read line; do
    echo "$line" > /var/log/oneclick.log
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, though there is a ';' missing before done

Comment: only if you put it all on one line. Newline, like semicolon, is a command separator